# oracle sql invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, ddl, dml

I am trying to run the following statement in the oracle database:

```
select nfl_player.first_name, nfl_player.last_name
from nfl_player
where player_id IN 
    (select nfl_player.player_id as pid
        from nfl_player
        where pid=nfl_team_roster.player_id
        and nfl_team_roster.team_id= 4
    );
```

For some reason when I run it, I get the following message:

```
and nfl_team_roster.team_id= 4
    *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "NFL_TEAM_ROSTER"."TEAM_ID": invalid identifier
```

I have double checked and I have my syntax right (or at least I believe so). The column exists.  I have included my schema for that table below.  What would be giving me this error?

```
CREATE TABLE NBA_Team_Roster(
roster_ID number primary key,
team_id number,
player_id number unique,
foreign key (team_id) references NBA_Team(team_id),
foreign key (player_id) references NBA_Player(player_id)
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your table named: **NBA**_Team_Roster, or "**nfl**_team_roster"?

Comment: You have twice `...from nfl_player...` but the name of your table is **`NBA_Team_Roster`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nfl_team_roster` table is not used in your query. I think you misplaced the table name in sub-query

```
SELECT first_name, 
       last_name 
FROM   nfl_player nf 
WHERE  player_id IN (SELECT ntr.player_id AS pid 
                     FROM   NBA_Team_Roster ntr --Here 
                     WHERE  nf.pid = ntr.player_id 
                            AND ntr.team_id = 4);
```

Use `Alias` name instead of full table name to refer columns it makes the query more readable.

Comment: I am trying to do something along the same lines in the following statement but I am getting the same invalid identifier error only this time its concerning the last `and` clause.
`select nfl_player.player_id
    from nfl_player, nfl_team_roster,nfl_game
  where nfl_player.player_id=nfl_team_roster.player_id
  and nfl_team_roster.team_id= nfl_game.team_id
  and nfl_game.start_time=700`

Comment: @Sal - check now.. Table name should be `NBA_Team_Roster` not `nfl_team_roster`

Comment: I made a mistake. It should've been NFL not NBA in the schema. Sorry about that.  It is all solved regarding the original issue. Did you see the comment I just posted above?

Comment: @Sal - What is the error you are getting. Post the error message and query in question

Answer (score 0):

there is a error in sub query you written, you misplaced the table name in sub-query and used alias name in join condition.

```
 select np.first_name, np.last_name
from nfl_player np
where np.player_id IN 
    (select r.player_id as pid
        from NBA_Team_Roster r
        where r.team_id= 4);
```